How to read the name of the music file currently playing in the active PowerPoint presentation using VBA from another application, e.g. Access?
I have an active PowerPoint presentation in show mode. The presentation, of course, consists of many slides. These slides have various animations and several music files per slide. Animations and music run according to the timeline, they do not require any clicking or other actions.
And here's the question:
How to use VBA from another program (e.g. Access) to read whether a music file is currently being played, and if so, which one? It would be ideal to read the progress of playing this file.
I know how to connect to PowerPoint, then to the active presentation and the currently presented slide and shape objects on the slide. However, I do not know how to obtain information about the currently playing music (or other multimedia) file.

Does this answer your question? How to use VBA to get the name of the music file that is currently playing in the active PowerPoint presentation

This is a duplicate of your earlier post, which has a reply or two already. Please don't double post.  Thanks.  (Earlier post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78506092/how-to-use-vba-to-get-the-name-of-the-music-file-that-is-currently-playing-in-th )
